# How does "Power" work in Tetris DX?

Tags: tetris-dx

In Tetris DX, your save file has a statistic called "Power", which goes up when you do well, and goes down when you don't.

I never got the instruction book with my copy (bought second-hand), so I don't know if it's explained in there, but I'm not sure exactly how Power operates.

I don't know if it's level-based, score-based, lines-based, how well you play (e.g. number of Tetris' you get in a round or how long you spend fast-dropping blocks) or if it's something else, as every round is different.

As shown in the photo below I'm at Power level 1288. I can't seem to get it much higher than that, even though I'm regularly hitting 300+ lines (and at one point hit 975 lines).

So, what factors determine your power, and what's the highest it can go?

[image: Tetris Power]

Comment: IIRC, it's just the average number of lines you clear each time you clear lines, multiplied by 400. I created a fresh profile and made one tetris and got a power of 1600.

Comment: @mm201 I created a new profile, cleared 3 lines at once, then immediately topped out, and my power was 26. Next, I created a new profile, got 1 Tetris then topped out, and my power was 75. Finally, I created a third profile, got 3 lines at once, then built up the board a bit before topping out. My score was 25 (not 26 like before!). So it's not lines multiplied by four. When I've got a second I'll open up an emulator and watch the power value to see what causes it to change.

Answer (score 0):

Gameplay data is recorded and stored as "POWER". Each profile has its own POWER data. Using a link cable, this data can be transferred to another cart.

In VS. COM, this can be used to play vs a CPU with a local profile, or a transfered profile's game data.

Your power increases as you play better games using your profile.

I am not sure if this is just a score the game assigns, or if any other stats or game data is taken into account.